# Directory Upload to HTTP

Tags: curl, http

Using `curl` with argument `--ftp-create-dirs`, I can upload blank directory to FTP/FTPS server. Is there any utility/tool by which I can upload blank/empty directory to HTTP/HTTPS server ?

Comment: Do you mean via HTTP ["PUT"](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-9.6) requests?  `curl` can support those with `-X PUT`.

Comment: @JigglyNaga, an example please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to upload data to a HTTP server is to use PUT. But be aware this option requires that the server knows how to receive a HTTP PUT stream, so you there should be a script in most situations.

I'm not sure if it can upload a directory or not, but for uploading data to a server using cURL, you need to follow the steps below:

### HTTP:

```
curl --upload-file yourUploadFile [HTTP Address]
```

### HTTPS:

```
curl --user login:password --upload-file your.file.txt [HTTPS Address]
```

**N.B.** in HTTPS upload way, add `--insecure` if you do not want cURL to check the certificate chain.

Comment: What if `thePathYouWantToUploadIn` is non-existing path ?

Comment: @SHW where you want the file to be uploaded on the server

Comment: @SHW just use the URL you, or the server you wanted to upload your file in. I will change edit my answer and change the address by `[URL]` to keep it simple.

Comment: @SHW I updated my answer.

Comment: I tried the given command but it ends up with the error "The page was not displayed because there was a conflict"

Comment: So you're getting Error 409. In this case the Web server thinks that the request submitted by the client cannot be completed because it conflicts with some rule already established. For instance, when you try to upload a file to the Web server which is older than the one already there - resulting in a version control conflict. You're using the command in the right way, but I mentioned earlier, web server should accept and knows how to handle HTTP PUT stream.

Comment: Read this [article](https://httpstatuses.com/409).